# how to update fragment on clock time

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to update fragment on clock time, say for example 8PM, with below logic. Unfortunately, it doesn't update the fragment. Any help/reference would be appreciated.

What I did:

1. registered an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in app's Application class as below:

   ```
       alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(AppConstants.INTENT_ACTION_UPDATE_DASHBOARD);
       alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

       // Set the alarm to start at Consulting start time
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
       alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
   ```
2. Listens for AlarmManager in Fragment as below:

   ```
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mDashboardUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter
           (AppConstants.INTENT_ACTION_UPDATE_DASHBOARD));
   ```
3. and performs actions if broadcast receives:

   ```
   private BroadcastReceiver mDashboardUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Dashboard updating...");
            updateCounters();
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a `PendingIntent` does not trigger a local broadcast. You cannot use `LocalBroadcastManager` here.

Second, using `AlarmManager` to update a UI is rather odd. If your UI exists, you have a process running, so you could use something in-process (e.g., `ScheduledExecutorService`) rather than fussing with `AlarmManager`.

Third, you are not taking into account that `set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)` and `calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)` might change the `Calendar` to be in the past. Imagine if you execute your first code snippet at 23:00, with `hour` set to be `22` and `minute` set to be `0`. The `Calendar` object that you create will be for today, but for 22:00 today, which was an hour before now (23:00). You need to check the `Calendar`, see if it is in the past, and if so, `add()` a day or otherwise adjust it to some future time.