# AlarmManager.setWindow vs. AlarmManager.set bug?

Tags: java, android

I would like to write an alarm clock app for Android using Java, and noticed that the onReceive function executes if the 'current time' is later than the 'set time' under the exact same day (as mentioned in the documentation).

The problem I am having with the set function is if I set the alarm for 8 am (for the very next day), and it is 11:00 at night when I set the alarm, the onReceive function will execute because 11 at night is later than 8 in the morning under the exact same day, so I would have to wait until 12 am before setting the alarm before I can get the desired results, researched on what to do, and found that I needed to use the setWindow function instead of the set function.

I already tried the setWindow function, and am still having the same problems (as if I am still using the set function).  I would like the onReceive function to execute only if the current time is under a minute after the set time. Also, how do I send the example codes and logs (since I am new to stackoverflow)? I indented 4 spaces, and am still getting the same error when trying to send. Thank you.

Comment: "so I would have to wait until 12 am before setting the alarm before I can get the desired results" -- or, you could add one day to the alarm time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945869/115145), third paragraph. "am still getting the same error when trying to send" -- what is the error?

Comment: Thank you, but what if I wanted it to wake me up on the same day, and automatically determine weather to do this or not?

Comment: You can't "wake me up on the same day" for times in the past. If the time of day for today results in a `Calendar` that is in the past, `add()` a day. If the time of day for today results in a `Calendar` that is in the future, just use that `Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

All the [`AlarmManager.set...`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) methods have a parameter `long triggerAtMillis`, which indicates a fixed time (interpreted depending on `type` parameter).

To get the millis, you can f.ex. use a `Calendar` object, as [hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933728/alarmmanager-setwindow-vs-alarmmanager-set-bug#comment65223451_38933728).

If you want more info, post code, (best: a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).